# Why we need the template keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, language-lawyer

A function template:

```
template<class T> T 
max(T a, T b){return (a > b)? a: b;}
```

when use it:

```
max<int>(a, b); // Yeah, the "<int>" is optional most of the time.
```

but if you allow, we can write template this way:

```
T max<class T>(T a, T b){return (a > b)? a: b;} 
//I know the return type T is not in its scope, don't focus on that.
```

Thus we can maintain the same form of declaration and using just like normal function does. and even don't need to introduce and type the keyword "template". I think class template would be the same? So is there any other reason make the template become the form we know today?

i changed the form so that you don't focus on the return type:

```
auto max<class T>(T a, T b) -> T {return (a > b)? a: b;}
//This is C++11 only and ugly i guess. 
//The type deduce happens at compile time 
//means that return type really didn't to be a problem.
```

Comment: That's just the syntax that was chosen. I believe there's no *real* compelling reason behind it. It's merely a simple decision.

Comment: You are too late by just few months when dey accepted c++11. Now you have to wait for next 20 years.

Comment: I don't remember that such variant was examined in _Design and Evolution of C++_, which is AFAIK the best source for rationale for things decided at that time (about 20 years ago).

Comment: A Q&A site is not a good format for subjective questions. However you are not the only one asking for this. The very David Abrahams (the guy behind the MPL) has an interesting blog article about a shorter syntax for template code: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/11/having-it-all-pythy-syntax/ He even wrote on the clang mailing list about it, and asked for help into changing the parser/semantic analysis to experiment with this syntax and check if it provoked ambiguities etc :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. knowing the reason can be better. There is times i don't understand why we need declaration(many language don't need that) but when i got the answer that it's goal is to help not to disturb i had a better mood when coding and known better how to write good code.

Comment: @Mike: I agree, but your question is so worded that it seemed (to me at least) a rant for a new syntax rather than a true inquiring question. It's just an impression, obviously.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The question is seemed to suggest a new syntax a little. But i really just explain what the things should be in my mind and ask why things be diffident. BTW, I still don't understand why static member in a class only a declaration and not a definition. but it's another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate answer that comes to my mind is:
Just because someone who laid out the proposal for templates said so and no one on the standards committee felt that typing those extra `8` characters would be an overhead.

On a different note:
The syntax of templates is complicated and intimidating to begin with, making sure of presence of the keyword `template` makes it more intuitive to a reader of code that they are dealing with templates and not any of the other beasts provided by C++ or any implementation specific constructs(read compiler extensions).

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `T` before you use it, so it really **must** be

```
<class T> T max(T a, T b){return (a > b)? a: b;}
```

But then its not clear what `<class T>` is - the compiler would most likely be confused about it. `template` in front makes clear that `<` are not operators but braces enclosing type declarations.

From that point of view, your second example should be possible, but keep in mind that this syntax is only possible with C++11 and templates were introduced much earlier.

Comment: There are languages that don't need `template<class T>` at all, and they are perfectly fine.

Comment: Scala, Rust. There are quite a number, I just don't remember many. This is definitely *not* a must. BTW, in C++ it is possible sometimes to use an identifier before it is declared (consider inline class methods calling each other: they don't require forward declarations), so even for C++, “T has to be declared first” sounds like a weak reason.

Comment: Good observation, but I think these are exceptions in C++. In general, I think you have to declare before you access, at least in C++. Other languages are of course not restricted like this.

Comment: @cschwan making function as a whole just the same as class does no harm. declare before use just only a way to assure that one don't introduce new names by accident(like misspell or typo or anything else), this syntax does not break the rule.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the problem relies in ease of compiler implementation: any names used in C++ have to be at least declared before being used to help compilers be able to parse from beginning (for reason I am not aware of). That's one reason you have the strange new syntaxe to declare functions, that allow defining the return type after the arguments.

So here the reason is that, reading your example, T is the first name used, but it is not declared before so the compiler have no clue what it is or what kind of expression it is in.

Answer (score 1):

You're quickly getting into parsing problems with that approach:

```
template <typename> int f(); // Current declaration syntax, type template argument.
template <int> int f();      // Current declaration syntax, non-type template argument.

void f<class>(); // New declaration syntax, type argument. 
void f<int>(); // New declaration syntax, non-type argument.
(void) f<int>(); // (void) is a cast , f is instantiation of f<class> with type int.
```

Comment: That's not a problem. `(void) f<int>();` would be treated as the same as `template<int> void f();` if it is alone. And will be treated as a cast when used as an rvalue. The same problem comes to normal function as well.

Comment: @Mike: Try to get the parsing entirely unambiguous. What about `f<int> f<int> ();` ? `f<int> (*f<int>) ();` ? `(f<int>*) (*f<int>) ();` ?

Comment: `f<int>` would be a type that is predefined i think because there is no parenthesis at the right side of it. I'm not sure if class names and function names can be overloaded or not. If that's allowed, it would be a function template the same as `template<int> f<int> f();`, the second one would be a pointer to the first one and the third one just the same as the second one except that the return type is different when they are alone. And there is no way to make any of those to be a cast.